Differentiate $trace(CWW^H)$ with respect to $W$
If I have the following $c =trace(CWW^H)$, where $W$ is a complex variable matrix and $C$ is a complex fixed matrix, then how I can find the derivative of $c$ with respect to $W$?

Use that $\operatorname{tr}$ is linear

how do you derive $W^H$ with respect to $W$? the conjugation function is not differentiable

Treating $W$ and $W^H$ as independent variables yields
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
\def\tr{\operatorname{Tr}}
c &= \tr\Big(CWW^H\Big) \quad=\quad \tr\Big(W^HC;W\Big) \
dc &=\tr\Big((W^HC);dW\Big) \implies \frac{\p c}{\p W} = (W^HC) \
}$$
(or the transpose of this depending on your preferred layout convention)
